# how to get touchcode events for android

Tags: android, shell

Can some one help me on  how to get a touchcode events that I can  send through adb to launch an app in my Android phone(iCS).
When I tried `getevent()` it is throwing me so many events. How do I know which touch event I have selected?

Answer (score 0):

getevent lets you filter by device as well as other things:

```
Usage: getevent [-t] [-n] [-s switchmask] [-S] [-v [mask]] [-d] [-p] [-i] [-l] [-q] [-c count] [-r] [device]
    -t: show time stamps
    -n: don't print newlines
    -s: print switch states for given bits
    -S: print all switch states
    -v: verbosity mask (errs=1, dev=2, name=4, info=8, vers=16, pos. events=32, props=64)
    -d: show HID descriptor, if available
    -p: show possible events (errs, dev, name, pos. events)
    -i: show all device info and possible events
    -l: label event types and names in plain text
    -q: quiet (clear verbosity mask)
    -c: print given number of events then exit
    -r: print rate events are received
```

so, use your touch device to filter the events, for example

```
getevent /dev/input/event0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the getevent command.

example:

```
getevent -ltr /dev/input/event0

EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   000002cd  
EV_ABS       ABS_MT_PRESSURE      00000027  
EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000002  
EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000016d  
EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    00000620  
EV_KEY       BTN_TOUCH            DOWN  
EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000  
EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   ffffffff  
EV_KEY       BTN_TOUCH            UP  
EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000             rate 15  
EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   000002ce  
EV_ABS       ABS_MT_PRESSURE      0000001f  
EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000003  
EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000001ab  
EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000002e6  
EV_KEY       BTN_TOUCH            DOWN  
EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000             rate 0  
EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000002e3  
EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000             rate 60  
EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000001ac  
EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000002de  
EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000             rate 123
```